# how to disable the jquery dialog buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

**My Needs:** I am using a jquery modal dialog. I have some buttons on it. I want to disable one button when It dialog opens but want to enable it after some specific operation.

**What i did:** I can disable the button by adding this statement`jQuery(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Issue')").attr("disabled", true).addClass("ui-state-disabled");`.

**Problem:** But now what I want is that when edit button is clicked I perform some action, after performing that action the `Issue' button become enable.

**My code is below.**

```
 jQuery(newdiv).dialog({
    width:500,
    height:275,
    dialogClass:'alert',
    modal: true,
    close: function(event, ui) { jQuery(newdiv).html(''); },
    buttons: {
        "issue":function()
        {

        },
        "Edit":function()
        {
          //here I am opening a new dialogue. When this child dialog is closed I want the `issue` button of parent dialogue to enablee.I have used this statement
          jQuery(this).find(".ui-dialog-buttonset button:contains('Issue')").removeAttr("disabled").removeClass("ui-state-disabled").addClass('ui-state-default');
        },
        "Cancel":function(){jQuery(this).dialog('close');},
    }
});
jQuery(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
jQuery(".ui-widget-content").css({'background':'none','background-color':'#FFFFFF'});
jQuery(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Issue')").attr("disabled", true).addClass("ui-state-disabled");
```

Comment: just set the attribute to false on edit's click...did you do that?

Comment: No you must remove the attribute disabled to enable something, the only precence of the attribute disables an input

Comment: @Nicola Peluchetti see my edited question

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's no need to mess around with the classes on the buttons and it probably isn't a good idea anyway. The buttons in a jQuery-UI dialog are [jQuery-UI buttons](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/) and they support `disable` and `enable` methods in the usual jQuery-UI style:

```
$button.button('enable');  // Enable the button
$button.button('disable'); // Disable the button
```

First of all, replace this:

```
jQuery(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Issue')").attr("disabled", true).addClass("ui-state-disabled");
```

With this:

```
jQuery('.ui-dialog button:nth-child(1)').button('disable');
```

Then, in your edit handler, do this:

```
jQuery('.ui-dialog button:nth-child(1)').button('enable');
```

To enable the button.

As far as the selectors go, the main dialog `<div>` has a `ui-dialog` class so we start off with `.ui-dialog`. Then, we want the buttons inside the dialog so we're looking for `<button>` elements; this gives us `.ui-dialog button`. The buttons in the dialog are listed from left to right in the same order as in the `buttons` option to the dialog. There are various ways to get the first button:

- [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)
- [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)
- [`:nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

I went with [`:nth-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) which is a CSS3 selector:

> The `:nth-child(an+b)` pseudo-class notation represents an element that has `an+b-1` siblings **before** it in the document tree, for any positive integer or zero value of `n`, and has a parent element.

So `button:nth-child(1)` is the first button. I figured that if you were doing things to one button, you'd probably end up doing things to other buttons so, for example, you could do `.ui-dialog button:nth-child(2)` to get the "Edit" button and that would line up nicely with the selector used for the "Issue" button.

Comment: Strange dude. Its working. But I am unable to understand this. Would you like to a little more explan it how you have done this. how `jQuery('.ui-dialog button:nth-child(1)'` find that specific button?

Comment: Dude this is awesome. Totally understood that. Outstanding. +1 for well explanation.

Comment: This was the only solution of many that worked for me. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
    "Edit":function()
    {
       //perform other actions
      jQuery(".ui-dialog-buttonset button:contains('Issue')").removeAttr("disabled").removeClass("ui-state-disabled").addClass('ui-state-default');
    },
```

Remember, an input element with the attribute disabled is always disabled, whatever value you set the attribute to: `$('input').attr('disabled', false)` is equal to `$('input').attr('disabled', 'disabled')`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually I am opening a new dialog on edit button. When new dialogue close I want to enable the `issue` button of parent dialog. I have also edited my question.

Comment: Is there only one button called issue?If so look at how i edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
"Edit":function()
        {
       jQuery(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Issue')")
             .removeAttr("disabled")
             .removeClass("ui-state-disabled")
             .addClass('ui-state-default');

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have other dialog in the context, this way
`jQuery('.ui-dialog button:nth-child(1)').button('disable');`
may cause some problem.

there is a few step to improve this :
1st: find the dialog handle

```
$mydialog = $("#divfordialog");
```

2nd: find the button panel

```
$buttonPanel = $mydialog.siblings(".ui-dialog-buttonpane");
```

3rd: find the target button, assume the button's name is BTN

```
$buttonwanttocontrol = $buttonPanel.find('button:contains("BTN")');
```

last: handle it(eg:disable it, enable it);

```
$buttonwanttocontrol.button("disable");
$buttonwanttocontrol.button("enable");
```

offently, we want to init our dialog button status when it open, this will work find:

```
$("divfordialog").dialog({
    ...
    buttons : {
        ...
        "BTN" : function () {},
        ...
    },
    open : function () {
        if (shouldDisableBtn()) {
            $(this).siblings(".ui-dialog-buttonpane").find('button:contains("BTN")').button("disable")
        }
    }
    ...
});
```